# How to efficiently loop through a dictionary when deleting elements from the same (mutated)

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I access a mutated dictionary:

I have two dictionary exact replica of each other. I have a requirement of deleting few elements during the loop based on few condition. The deletion happens but the dictionary iterates for each elements, I see why, but I wanted to know if there is anything that can be done to avoid the extra loops for the deleted keys.

For example

```
a={0:{1,2,3}, 1:{2,3,4}, 2:{6,7,8}, 3:{3,4,5}, 4:{7,8,9}}
b={0:{1,2,3}, 1:{2,3,4}, 2:{6,7,8}, 3:{3,4,5}, 4:{7,8,9}}

for key, values in a.items():
    print key ,  a
    for key2, values2 in b.items():
        if key==0 and key2==3:
            del a[3]
        if key==1 and key2==2:
            del a[2]
```

When compute the output of the above code I get the below:

```
0 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 2: set([8, 6, 7]), 3: set([3, 4, 5]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
1 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 2: set([8, 6, 7]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
2 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
3 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
4 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
```

The iteration is done for all the rows even for 2 and 3 which I delete amid the loop.

The output I want is somewhat similar to

```
0 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 2: set([8, 6, 7]), 3: set([3, 4, 5]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
1 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 2: set([8, 6, 7]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
4 {0: set([1, 2, 3]), 1: set([2, 3, 4]), 4: set([8, 9, 7])}
```

How do I do it using dictionary, I want to use dictionary because average case complexity of deletion in dictionary is o(1) where as the same in list is o(n)...

Since my data set is too large I would need a optimized way of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a simple start, your `if` statements are exclusive, either one or none are true, not both, so use an `elif` for the second `if`.  Won't make much difference, but every little helps.

Comment: Could you please *explain in plain English* what you are trying to accomplish with this algorithm? You have two sets of key/value pairs and you want to do what with them?

Comment: Why are you even looping? `if a.get(0,False) and b.get(3, False): del a[3]` will do the same thing with no loop.

Comment: Hi cdarke, thanks for the reply, I am aware of the If else condition. The code here is just a reference, I wanted to show that even if I am deleting entries from the dictionary, My first for loop hold the same dictionary. I want to know If there is any method by which the dictionary rebuilds every time when called by the for loop.

Comment: If Python destroyed and rebuilt sequences for each iteration of a loop it would take ages to get anything done.

Comment: Ya thanks lanAuld, that is what I was looking for... I am new to python, So wanted to confirm if it can be done or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the dictionary size when you are looping over it. When you use:

```
for key, values in a.items():
    ...
```

`a.items()` returns a `list` in `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2).....]`  format. So exactly you are not interating over the dictionary.
 Thats why even when you delete the dictionary elements `a.items()` have still got it and you are getting same in output.

To answer your question about doing this efficiently: while iterating over a dictionary you can not. But if you are sure about the `key` that you want to delete. Then you can simply use:

```
if key in a:
    del a[key]
```